# Why does my dog starts drinking water when he sees people dancing?

Tags: dogs, behavior

My dog starts drinking water continously when he sees anybody dancing, even though he may have just drank enough water. No matter how much water he drank before , if he sees anyone dancing he runs to drink water again.

I am just curious to know what is causing this behaviour. Is something i need to worry about?

Comment: What kind of dancing? The dog could be hiding his confusion or perhaps the dance is just not very interesting.

Comment: Is he a rescue dog? He may be confusing people dancing with people fighting; and drinking may be an escape mechanism, especially if he is unable to leave the house.

Comment: @Mick No he is not a rescue dog. He is a young dog ,adopted,and been pet for a month now. And he has places to go like garden, terrace but he prefers to go inside the house to drink water

Comment: @Beo just a casual dancing like in small parties

Comment: @wrangler I have seen cats and dogs react strangely to people dancing or otherwise moving strangely. I can say with 100% certainty that canine thirst inspired by viewing dancing is noting to be concerned about.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that your dog is drinking water as a nervous response to not being able to comprehend why the humans are moving around like that (they don't normally move like that)! Dogs with anxiety lick obsessively, tear things up, or develop other nervous 'ticks' (such as drinking water while under anxiety).

Look for other signs that your dog could be uncomfortable, and verify that this behavior is only triggered by certain circumstances (like the dancing).

If it's possible your dog is repeating this behavior more frequently (but maybe it was only first noticed during the dancing), consider a vet checkup, as it's possible there could be a [more serious problem](http://www.pethealthnetwork.com/dog-health/dog-diseases-conditions-a-z/my-dog-drinking-a-lot-water-polydipsia).

Comment: Yes as far as i know in a month he shows this behaviour only while dancing